# C to MIPS convert

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mips

Can anyone help me convert the C code below to MIPS code? I'm supposed to use recursion and get 21 - 2 as the final answer. Thanks!

```
/*
x is a pointer to a linked list node and is not null.
Return the min value stored in the linked list.

Assume each node is stored in memory as an int (value) followed by a pointer to the next node (next), each a word wide.
You must write it with recursion.  */

int findMin(node *x) {
    if(x->next == NULL)
        return x->value;
    else {
        int min = findMin(x->next);
        if(min < x->value) 
            return min;
        else
            return x->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... use a compiler?

Comment: @tjameson The second paragraph of the comment is definitely the phrasing a Professor or TA would use.

Comment: @EricUrban - Hence the question. It was more retorical than anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -S -o foo.asm foo.c
```

Comment: Is there any way I can award you a troll tag?

Comment: @EricUrban I sincerely hope so. That would be something of an accomplishment.

Comment: I'm just hoping this guy turns in the output of the gcc compiler as his homework. His professor will either be very impressed, very confused, or just fail him and move on.

Comment: @EricUrban I think options #2 and #3 are likely - if the prof is savant enough to recognize GCC-style assembler output, then #3, if he isn't, then #2.

Comment: +2 if you change to -O3...